# Join document inside nested array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My first collection, called `Scenes` looks like this:

```
{
  sceneId: "id1",
  contentId: "contentId1",
  comments: [{
    comment: "abc",
    userId: "test1"
  },
  {
    comment: "def",
    userId: "test2"
  }]
},
{
  sceneId: "id2",
  contentId: "contentId2",
  comments: [{
    comment: "abc",
    userId: "test1"
  },
  {
    comment: "def",
    userId: "test2"
  }]
}
```

Any my second collection, called `Userdatas`, looks like this:

```
{
  userId: "test1",
  profilPicture: "def.jpg"
},
{
  userId: "test2",
  profilPicture: "abc.jpg"
}
```

And I want to join them in a way, that I get the following:

```
{
  sceneId: "id1",
  contentId: "contentId1",
  comments: [{
    comment: "abc",
    userId: "test1",
    profilPicture: "def.jpg"
  },
  {
    comment: "def",
    userId: "test2",
    profilPicture: "abc.jpg"
  }]
},
{
  sceneId: "id2",
  contentId: "contentId2",
  comments: [{
    comment: "abc",
    userId: "test1",
    profilPicture: "def.jpg"
  },
  {
    comment: "def",
    userId: "test2",
    profilPicture: "abc.jpg"
  }]
}
```

and I have no idea how to do this, all my previous attempts failed. Help is appreciated! The key problem is, that the `$group` operator will not show the `contentId`, when grouping via the `sceneId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First `$unwind` `comments` array to destructure and join by `comments.userId`.
- Then `$lookup` that is like a JOIN, to merge `userId`s between collections generating a object called `data`.
- Destructure `$data` to get values.
- Add `profilPicture` to the object `comments` using `$set`.
- `$group` by `sceneId` adding all `comments` into an array.
- And use `$projection`  to show only fields you want.

```
db.Scenes.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$comments"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Userdatas",
      "localField": "comments.userId",
      "foreignField": "userId",
      "as": "data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "comments.profilPicture": "$data.profilPicture"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$sceneId",
      "comments": {
        "$push": "$comments"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "sceneId": "$_id",
      "comments": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bQVwyjalh9Q)

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the documents in `Scenes` collection have multiple other attributes that I want to retrieve as well. But when I use the `$group` operator, the values all disappear. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: You can add `"contentId": {"$first": "$contentId"}` into `$group` stage like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/duEkp6CWOxc)